# Is this the right pure code for executing a click event with the eventListener for the same element in JS?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

The only element that i have in the DOM is the input for submiting. after that i created a DIV and appended it to the body and added some style and set some attributes to that. I then assigned two events for the input , each one running a seperated click event and a function. The function that i want to execute is to change the background color  of the elements. When i click now the input,  instead of running the first function or "functionOne" it runs the "functionTwo. In the console  the "functionOne" is showing me as "function is not defined".  The code is here below:

```
 var btn=document.getElementById("submit");



var div = document.createElement("DIV");
var x=document.body.appendChild(div);

    x.style.width="250px";
    x.style.height="250px";
    x.style.backgroundColor="red";

    x.setAttribute("ID","box");
    x.setAttribute("CLASS","box")

console.log(x);

btn.addEventListener("click",functionOne);
btn.addEventListener("click",functionTwo);

var c =function functionOne(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="blue";
};
console.log(c);


function functionTwo(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="grey";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

it has to do with function declaration vs function expression.

https://medium.com/@mandeep1012/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions-b43646042052

when you write var c you are declaring a variable that's value is a function.
functionTwo is a function expression.

when its compiled, functionTwo is hoisted to the top of the code and can be read even though its written towards the end.

Solution 1:

move your event listeners to the bottom of the code

Solution 2:

make both functions function expressions

Answer (score 0):

You have used function expression. c is name of function now. var c = function() and var c = function functionOne() are same things. See below will work.

```js
var btn=document.getElementById("submit");



var div = document.createElement("DIV");
var x=document.body.appendChild(div);

    x.style.width="250px";
    x.style.height="250px";
    x.style.backgroundColor="red";

    x.setAttribute("ID","box");
    x.setAttribute("CLASS","box")

console.log(x);
btn.addEventListener("click",functionTwo);

var c =function(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="blue";
};
console.log(c);
btn.addEventListener("click",c);


function functionTwo(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor="grey";
};
```

```html
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Your case, pressing the button will trigger two functions at once. This can be seen in the logs.

```js
let btn=document.getElementById("submit");
let div = document.createElement("DIV");
    div.style.width="250px";
    div.style.height="250px";
    div.style.backgroundColor="red";

    div.setAttribute("id","box");
    div.setAttribute("class","box")
document.body.appendChild(div);
// you can use only div variable 
console.log(div);

btn.addEventListener("click",functionOne);
btn.addEventListener("click",functionTwo);


function functionOne(){
console.log('1');
    div.style.backgroundColor="blue";
};

function functionTwo(){
console.log('2');
    div.style.backgroundColor="grey";
};
```

```html
<button id = "submit">submit</button>
```